# Show $I$ is a principal ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

> The setup is we have ideals $I,J,K$ of some commutative ring $R$ such that $ I\subset J $,
>
> $K = \{r \in R \mid rJ \subset I\}$ and $J,K$ are principal ideals. I am then asked to show that $I$ is also a principal ideal.

I got that since $\exists\; j,k\in R$ such that $J = (j), K = (k)$, then $r_1r_2jk \in R \;\forall \; r_1,r_2 \in R$

and so $(jk) \subset I$

I am under the impression that $(jk) =I$ so I would like to show that $I \subset (jk) $ but I'm not completely sure how.

I know $I \subset J = (j) \Rightarrow \; \forall \; i \in I, \exists\; r \in R$ such that:

$i = rj$ and now I'm stuck.

I don't know how to proceed or even if my approach is right currently. I am right in my suspicion that $I = (jk)$? Should I be trying to get a contradiction by assuming I is not a principal ideal instead of finding the generator directly?

Any hints or help you might be able to offer would be very much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $I \subset J$, and $J = (j)$, so for any $i \in I$, we can find $r \in R$ such that $i = rj$. If we can show that this $r$ is in $K$, then $i \in (jk)$.  So we need to check that $rJ \subset I$, hence let $j' \in J$, and aim to prove $rj' \in I$.  We have $j' = r' j$, so $rj' =rr'j = r'i \in I$, since $I$ is an ideal.

So, for any $i \in I$, $i \in (jk)$, and hence $I \subset (jk)$.

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful!